# Match Multiple rows of same columns in Table - MySql

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table as follows.

```
+------------+-------------+---------+
| productid  | attributeid | valueid |
+------------+-------------+---------+
| 1011052312 |      331100 | 1543697 |
| 1011052312 |    33113319 | 1534108 |
| 1011098009 |       33129 | 2655849 |
| 1011052380 |      331100 | 1543697 |
| 1011052380 |    33113319 | 1233908 |
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

Now I need to fetch only those `productid` who has very selected set of attribute value pair. Say for example I need to fetch a product who's attribute `331100` has value `1543697` and attribute `33113319` has value `1534108`. Product `1011052312` satisfy this condition.

One thing to note is that I should avoid multiple joins because there can be a long list of attributes that I need to match. And for each attribute there can be any number of possible value.

Comment: Have you tried a simple select: `Select distinct productid from table where (attributeid=331100 and valueid=1543697) or (attributeid=33113319 and valueid=1534108)`  ?

Comment: I need to match all attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common problem, select all the products matching at least one attribute, group them, count how many attributes each product has and then use a `HAVING` clause to select only the products which have all the attributes. Something like this:

```
SELECT productid
FROM table
WHERE (attributeid=331100 and valueid=1543697)
OR (attributeid=33113319 and valueid=1534108)
GROUP BY productid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying the same thing - I can't remember if the EXPLAIN is the same or not, so this might be slower...

```
SELECT productid 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE (attributeid,valueid) IN ((331100,1543697)
                                ,(33113319,1534108)
                                )
 GROUP
    BY productid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```